# Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus QueueProperties property DefaultMessageTimeToLive not updating correctly

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I'm trying to leverage the Time To Live property of Azure Service Bus Queues to clear the queue if it gets backed up. I've been trying to use the DefaultMessageTimeToLive property on the queue to do this by setting it to one second like so

```
private static ServiceBusAdministrationClient client = new ServiceBusAdministrationClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ServiceBusNamespaceConnectionString"));
QueueProperties properties = await client.GetQueueAsync(queueName);
properties.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
```

However, after executing this code, the TimeSpan has stayed the same on the Azure portal and no messages have expired. I'm guessing because the setting is simply set locally. How would I get these changes to be set on the actual queue itself?

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else that comes across this, use the UpdateQueueAsync call to do this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).